# Question on Category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

i have a question how to prove that

the category of groups and morphisms of groups  is realy a category ?

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing you must know is: what exactly is a category. For this have a look at http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf

Comment: i know what is a category so i must prove that a)$h\circ(g\circ f)=(h\circ g)\circ f$ for every $h,g,f$ and b) tere existe a unique $i_X\in Mor(X,X)$ such that $i_X\circ g=g, f\circ i_X=f $ for $f:X\rightarrow  Y,g:Y\rightarrow X$  but i don't know how to prove this ?

Comment: Yes, associativity is one of the parts of the definition. Also you must show the existence of identities, that the homsets are disjoint. The things you find under 3.1. This for groups as objects and homomorphisms between them as morphisms (also called arrows).

Comment: the morphisms here are functions. Are you able to prove the associativity of composition of functions?

Comment: there is the prof in the book ?

Comment: No, in the book you find the definition. I will give you a hint on associativity.

Comment: @drhab i know that the composition of function is associative but i don't khow how to prove it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are functions then $f\circ g$ is by definition the
function $x\mapsto f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$. This way we have
$h\circ\left(f\circ g\right)\left(x\right)=h\left(f\circ g\left(x\right)\right)=h\left(f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)=\left(h\circ f\right)\left(g\left(x\right)\right)=\left(h\circ f\right)\circ g\left(x\right)$ showing that $h\circ\left(f\circ g\right)$ and $\left(h\circ f\right)\circ g$ are the same functions.

Comment: oh so we do this directly that's all we have to prove on associativity ?

Comment: yes, this is enough for associativity when it comes to morphisms that are functions wich is indeed the case in the category of groups.

Comment: and for the identity what is the case where we can't find this identity ?

Comment: For every group $G$ there is an automorphism $id_{G}:G\rightarrow G$
defined by $id_{G}\left(x\right)=x$. That is the identity of object/group
$G$.

Comment: thank you, can you tel me why whene we are on topological space we need the continuity of the applications to have a category ? thank you

Comment: Every category (Top, Grp, Set,...) is characterized by objects, morphisms. In the category of Set the morphisms are functions, in Top continuous functions, in Grp grouphomomorphisms. If you  want to know more about that then you will have to follow a course or read a book about it. This is really not the place to go deeper into this.

Answer (score 4):

When you don't immediately understand why the category of groups is a category, and in fact you don't know why the composition of functions is associative, you are not mature yet in order to learn category theory. It really doesn't make sense. The answers here explain you basic set theory and algebra. This is somewhat a prerequisite for doing category theory.