# Question on functors

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

please i need help,how to prove that

"the functor (covariant) "fundamental group", of the category of pointed topological spaces in the category of groups" is really a functor

What i must do to prove it ?

please, thank you.

Comment: You need to check that whenever you have a morphism of pointed topological spaces, this gives rise to a morphism of groups, and that these morphisms are compatible (as described in the definitions).

Comment: ah ok , please What it means here "fundamental group"?

Comment: You ought to have a definition of that somewhere. If you have not seen the fundamental group of a pointed topological space before, you will have a really hard time doing this exercise.

Comment: no i meane who is the fundamental group here , the functor , or who ?

Comment: The functor is the thing that assigns to each pointed topological space $X$ the fundamental group of $X$.

Comment: ooo i dont have this in my definition , where i can found it ?

Comment: if I take an object of the category of pointed topological spaces that is to say a couple $(X, x)$ how can you associate a group $F((X, x))$?

Comment: Is this an exercise in category theory that just assumed you know about the fundamental group? Because to me it looked like an exercise in algebraic topology, where the fundamental group is usually one of the first things you see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11146/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-tobias-kildetoft)

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Dear Vrouvrou, It will be much easier for someone to answer this question if you give some more background.  E.g. if you don't already know the definition of the fundamental group (say from an algebraic topology course) then you won't be able to do this exercise in any meaningful way.  Where did you come across this question?  Regards,

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/530304/1650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put the definitions here so that you can hopefully work through the problem yourself.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be categories. A **functor** $F\colon\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ is an assignment, to every object $A\in \mbox{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ an object $F(A)\in \mbox{Obj}(\mathcal{D})$ and to every morphism $f\colon A\rightarrow A'\in\mbox{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$, a morphism $F(f)\colon F(A)\rightarrow F(A')\in\mbox{Mor}(\mathcal{D})$ such that for composable morphisms $f,g$, we have $$F(f\circ g)=F(f)\circ F(g)$$ and for the identities $\mbox{Id}_A$, we have $F(\mbox{Id}_A)=\mbox{Id}_{F(A)}$.

Let $X$ be a topological space with base point $x_0$ and let $P=\{\gamma\colon[0,1]\rightarrow X\mid \gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=x_0\}$ be the set of all loops in $X$ based at $x_0$. We define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set $P$ by $\gamma\sim\gamma'$ is $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are homotopic functions relative to their end points. We then define a new a new set $$\pi_1(X,x_0)=P/{\sim}$$ which is the set of classes of homotopic relative to end points loops in $X$ based at $x_0$. The set $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ has a natural group structure $\#$ given by $[\gamma]\#[\gamma']=[\gamma\wedge\gamma']$ where here $\gamma\wedge\gamma'\colon[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is the loop defined by $$(\gamma\wedge\gamma')(t)=\begin{cases}\gamma(2t)&\mbox{ if }t\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\ \gamma'(2t-1)&\mbox{ if } t\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{cases}$$ and we call the group $(\pi_1(X,x_0),\#)$ the fundamental group of $X$, based at $x_0$.

To every basepoint preserving map $f\colon (X,x_0)\rightarrow (X',x_0')$ (so $f(x_0)=x_0'$), there is a natural induced homomorphism, which we denote by $\pi_1(f)$, on the level of fundamental groups defined by $$\pi_1(f)([\gamma])=[f\circ\gamma].$$

The question you are being asked is to show that $\pi_1\colon\mathbf{Top}_*\rightarrow\mathbf{Grp}$ which assigns to based spaces their fundamental group, and to the basepoint preserving maps between pointed spaces their induced homomorphisms on the level of groups, is a functor. To do this, you need to verify that the conditions mentioned at the start of this answer for the definition of a functor are all satisfied.